# Elastic Search: Find All Records By Single Phrase

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I am using elastic-search-1.4.4.And here is my query:

```
   { 
    "query": { 
          "filtered": { 
             "filter": { "term": { "Name": "n" } } 
        } 
     } 
   }
```

And Here is my Index documents:

```
   {
     "took" : 2,
     "timed_out" : false,
     "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
     "failed" : 0
    },
     "hits" : {
       "total" : 12,
       "max_score" : 1.0,
       "hits" : [ {
       "_index" : "mytry",
       "_type" : "users",
       "_id" : "23",
       "_score" : 1.0,
         "_source":{"ID":23,"Name":"Abudul Rafay","Email":"a","Password":"afasd"}
}, {
       "_index" : "mytry",
       "_type" : "users",
       "_id" : "28",
       "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source":{"ID":28,"Name":"helo","Email":"helo","Password":"heko"}
}, {
       "_index" : "mytry",
      "_type" : "users",
      "_id" : "30",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":30,"Name":"nup","Email":"nup","Password":"nup"}
}, {
     "_index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "31",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":31,"Name":"apex","Email":"apex","Password":"apex"}
}, {
     "_index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "29",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":29,"Name":"change","Email":"change","Password":"change"}
},   {
       "_index" : "mytry",
    "_type" : "users",
      "_id" : "24",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":24,"Name":"rafay","Email":"hello","Password":"fasfas"}
}, {
     "_index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "32",
     "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"ID":32,"Name":"newtry","Email":"newtry","Password":"newtry"}
}, {
      "index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "25",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":25,"Name":"r rafay ","Email":"r rafay","Password":"r rafay"}
}, {
     "_index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "19",
     "_score" : 1.0,
     "_source":{"ID":19,"Name":"n","Email":"a","Password":"a"}
}, {
     "_index" : "mytry",
     "_type" : "users",
     "_id" : "26",
     "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source":{"ID":26,"Name":"New User","Email":"New","Password":"new"}
      } ]
      }
   }
```

Here is my result after run Above Query:

```
     {
      "took" : 2,
      "timed_out" : false,
      "_shards" : {
      "total" : 5,
      "successful" : 5,
      "failed" : 0
     },
     "hits" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [ {
            "_index" : "mytry",
            "_type" : "users",
             "_id" : "19",
            "_score" : 1.0,
          "_source":{"ID":19,"Name":"n","Email":"a","Password":"a"}
          } ]
        }
       }
```

So, I want to get all records that is started or contains word 'n' in Name Field.I have try with aggregation but its not working.

Comment: In order to do that, you'll need to use the Ngram Token filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the wildcard query for this. The term query wil check on exact matches.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html